# Visual Studio EnvDTE.Expression slowing down

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, envdte

I have a Visual Studio addin for Visual Studio 2010 which evaluates a number of expressions (including variables in the current stack frame).  It is making repeated calls to:

```
foreach (EnvDTE.Expression expression in dte.Debugger.CurrentStackFrame.Locals)
```

and

```
dte.Debugger.GetExpression("CanSerializeToString(" + expression + ")", false);
```

and

```
dte.Debugger.GetExpression("SerializeToString(" + expression + ")", false);
```

where "SerializeToString" methods are defined in the client application being debugged.

I've noticed that the more expressions it evaluates, the slower it gets.  When I expanded the contents of an array, I can sit and watch as it takes over a second to evaluate each array element expression, and each one takes longer than the previous.

Is there some kind of cleanup I need to do after evaluating an expression so it doesn't get slower and slower and slower?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this isn't directly answering your question but it looks like you are trying to do something very similar to this addin:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c6a21c68-f815-4895-999f-cd0885d8774f

The strategy I use is I don't have the client code creating the serializer but it's done in the addin code and that runs fairly quickly. It's open source so feel free to take a look.

https://github.com/OmarElabd/ObjectExporter